# Why removing else causes recursive function to repeat the result?

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

When I execute the following code on Python console using the below statement,

```
for L in permute([12, 32, 3]):
    print(L)
```

for the code below,

```
def permute(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        yield L
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(L)):
            L[0], L[i] = L[i], L[0]
            for L1 in permute(L[1:]):
                yield [L[0]] + L1
```

each result appears just once. But, if I remove `else` and remove the associated indentation of the code below it, I receive each result twice. 
Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generators):

> The big difference between `yield` and a `return` statement is that on reaching a `yield` the generator’s state of execution is suspended and local variables are preserved. On the next call to the generator’s `__next__()` method, the function will resume executing.

So this happens because `if` body doesn't break execution, so it moves forward to the next `yield` statement and with `else` clause reaches end of function and implicitly returns.

Check

```
def counter(step):
    assert step >= 0, ('Can count only from non-negative number, but found '
                       + str(step))
    if step == 0:
        print('Reached end')
        yield step
    print('Step', step)
    for sub_step in counter(step - 1):
        yield sub_step

>>> list(counter(1))

Step 1
Reached end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 13, in <module>
Step 0
  File "<input>", line 8, in counter
  File "<input>", line 8, in counter
  File "<input>", line 3, in counter
AssertionError: Can count only from non-negative number, but found -1
```

and

```
def counter(step):
    assert step >= 0, ('Can count only from non-negative number, but found '
                       + str(step))
    if step == 0:
        print('Reached end')
        yield step
    else:
        print('Step', step)
        for sub_step in counter(step - 1):
            yield sub_step
    # implicitly returns here

>>> list(counter(1))
Step 1
Reached end
```

As we can see without `else` execution will continue and call `counter` with `step` equal to `-1`.

So you can leave `else` or refactor your `if` clause and add `return` statement into it to explicitly finish execution like

```
def permute(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        yield L
        return
    for i in range(0, len(L)):
        L[0], L[i] = L[i], L[0]
        for L1 in permute(L[1:]):
            yield [L[0]] + L1
```

## Further reading

- [Generators](https://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generators).
- [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) and [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) statements.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are `yield`ing twice, if there is no `else` loop.

Comment: glad to help. :) would you like to accept the answer as well.